# unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem which i do not see on line 9 of my code (which is the second line for you guys). I searched stackoverflow for it, but the problem still seems to be hiding for me...

Code is:

```
$otsi_array(
    'soiduki_tuup' => array(
        ''                      => 'Kõik',
        '4X4'                   => '4X4',
        'Kaubik C'              => 'Kaubik C',
        'MAHTUNIVERSAAL'        => 'MAHTUNIVERSAAL',
        'Motoroller'            => 'Motoroller',
        'Sõiduauto'             => 'Sõiduauto',
        'Traktor'               => 'Traktor',
        'Veoauto'               => 'Veoauto'
    );
```

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pay attention to the syntax...

```
<?php
$otsi_array = array (
    'soiduki_tuup' => array (
        ''                      => 'Kõik',
        '4X4'                   => '4X4',
        'Kaubik C'              => 'Kaubik C',
        'MAHTUNIVERSAAL'        => 'MAHTUNIVERSAAL',
        'Motoroller'            => 'Motoroller',
        'Sõiduauto'             => 'Sõiduauto',
        'Traktor'               => 'Traktor',
        'Veoauto'               => 'Veoauto'
        )
    );
?>
```

Comment: sigh, such thing was between my eyes? darn me. I'm really sorry for wasting your time guys and thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're missing an array declaration:

```
$otsi_array = array(
    'soiduki_tuup' => array(
        ...
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$otsi = array(
    'soiduki_tuup' => array(
        ''                      => 'Kõik',
        '4X4'                   => '4X4',
        'Kaubik C'              => 'Kaubik C',
        'MAHTUNIVERSAAL'        => 'MAHTUNIVERSAAL',
        'Motoroller'            => 'Motoroller',
        'Sõiduauto'             => 'Sõiduauto',
        'Traktor'               => 'Traktor',
        'Veoauto'               => 'Veoauto'
    );
```

Or `$otsi_array = array( /* .. */ );`.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a variable name followed by brackets, `$otsi_array()` in your case, PHP will treat it as "Call the function or object named in the variable, using whatever is between the brackets as parameters".  The syntax between your brackets is illegal as an argument to pass to a function, so PHP throws the error.

It should be:

```
$otsi_array = array(
    'soiduki_tuup' => array(
        ''                      => 'Kõik',
        '4X4'                   => '4X4',
        'Kaubik C'              => 'Kaubik C',
        'MAHTUNIVERSAAL'        => 'MAHTUNIVERSAAL',
        'Motoroller'            => 'Motoroller',
        'Sõiduauto'             => 'Sõiduauto',
        'Traktor'               => 'Traktor',
        'Veoauto'               => 'Veoauto'
    )
);
```